# Abrir archivos DTS en Sql Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Deseo migrar varios paquetes de Integration Services del sql 2000 que tienen extensión .DTS a DTSX.

Actualmente cuento con Sql Server 2012 y no logro pasarlos a DTSX.

¿Hay alguna manera directa de migrarlos, sin necesidad de convertirlos a 2005 y 2008? ya que no tengo permiso para instalar algún programa

Answer (score 2):

Pues no, **no hay manera**. A partir de SQL Server 2012 se dejó de dar soporte a estas funcionalidades

- DTS runtime
- DTS API
- El wizard que ayudaba con la mgiración de paquetes DTS simples a IS (Integration Services)
- Soporte para paquetes DTS dentro del SQL Server Management Studio
- Ejecución paquetes DTS

Por experiencia propia, también he tenido que migrar DTS, pero en mi caso tuve que hacerlo al Integration Services 2008 (2005 también es una opción) para luego migrarlo al IS 2012. Puedes ver algunos datos más [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986522/running-dts-packages-on-sql-server-2012) y [acá también](https://forums.asp.net/t/1867076.aspx?DTS+on+SQLS2000+to+SQLS2012)

Espero haber respondido la pregunta

Comment: Bienvenido Mokz. Muy buena respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Sé que el post es antiguo. Pero la solución sería importar los paquetes en proyecto de Visual Studio 2008. Así los conviertes a .dtsx y ya puedes usarlos en proyectos de versiones posteriores.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!!! podrias mirar el [tour] y tambien [answer]. fijate que justamente quien pregunto, dice que no quiere pasar por 2008...

Comment: Cierto, pero no hay otra forma, son versiones muy lejanas, la manera lamentablemente sería esa, pasar por 2008. Espero que lo consiguiera.